# How to for_each through a list

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create EBS volumes from map(map). I am able to create EC2 instances using same variable, but failing in EBS volume creation.

variable.tf

```
variable "ec2_details" {
type = any
default = {
    ec2_1 = {
        ami_id = "ami-006dcf34c09e50022"
        instance_type = "t2.micro"
        ec2_ebs_volume_size = [10,20]
        subnet_id = "subnet-09dc67828b86e0796"
        availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
    }
    ec2_2 = {

        ami_id = "ami-006dcf34c09e50022"
        instance_type = "t1.micro"
        ec2_ebs_volume_size = [10,20]
        subnet_id = "subnet-0ad1066b3d501c763"
        availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
    }
  }
}
```

main.tf

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2_instance" {
  for_each                                  = var.ec2_details
  ami                                       = each.value.ami_id
  availability_zone                         = each.value.availability_zone
  instance_type                             = each.value.instance_type
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs_volume" {
  for_each                                  = var.ec2_details
  availability_zone                         = each.value.availability_zone
  size                                      = element(each.value.ec2_ebs_volume_size,index(each.value.ec2_ebs_volume_size,length(each.value.ec2_ebs_volume_size) - 1))
}
```

I am getting following error, it looks like it is failed to iterate through list of EBS volume size.

```
│ │ Error: Error in function call
│
│   on main.tf line 11, in resource "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs_volume":
│   11:   size                                      = element(each.value.ec2_ebs_volume_size,index(each.value.ec2_ebs_volume_size,length(each.value.ec2_ebs_volume_size) - 1))
│     ├────────────────
│     │ while calling index(list, value)
│     │ each.value.ec2_ebs_volume_size is tuple with 2 elements
│
│ Call to function "index" failed: item not found.
╵
╷
│ Error: Error in function call
│
│   on main.tf line 11, in resource "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs_volume":
│   11:   size                                      = element(each.value.ec2_ebs_volume_size,index(each.value.ec2_ebs_volume_size,length(each.value.ec2_ebs_volume_size) - 1))
│     ├────────────────
│     │ while calling index(list, value)
│     │ each.value.ec2_ebs_volume_size is tuple with 2 elements
│
│ Call to function "index" failed: item not found.
```

It is failed to iterate through list to get EBS volume sizes.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind your choice of using the element function in such a way?

Comment: I am trying to get each value (EBS size) using element function, but it is not accepting list inside map. my logic seems incorrect on for_each.

Answer (score 0):

I guess from your question that you intend to declare one `aws_instance` for each element of `var.ec2_details`, but you intend to declare one `aws_ebs_volume` for each nested element of the `ec2_ebs_volume_size` attributes.

`for_each` has two main requirements for the collection you provide it:

- It must have one element for each instance you want to declare.
- It must be either a map, an object, or a set of strings.

`var.ec2_details` is a suitable value for your `aws_instance` resource because it is an object with one attribute per EC2 instance you want to declare, but it is not a suitable value for your `aws_ebs_volume` resource. Instead, you'll need to derive a new value that unpacks each of the individual EBS volumes to be a top-level element.

Because `for_each` requires a map-like value, your list of numbers is not sufficient. Instead, I suggest defining this data structure as taking a map of objects where each object represents a volume, like this:

```
variable "ec2_details" {
  type = map(object({
    ami_id            = string
    instance_type     = string
    subnet_id         = string
    ec2_ebs_volumes = map(object({
      size = number
    }))
  }))

  # NOTE: It's incorrect to use "any" for a module where
  # you are depending this value having a particular type.
  # "any" is for situations where you are just passing the
  # value verbatim to an external system and so you really
  # don't actually care what type it has, but that's not
  # true here because this module will fail if the given
  # value does not match the above type constraint.
}
```

The following would be a suitable value for this variable, equivalent to what you showed in your question:

```
  ec2_details = {
    ec2_1 = {
      ami_id            = "ami-006dcf34c09e50022"
      instance_type     = "t2.micro"
      subnet_id         = "subnet-09dc67828b86e0796"
      ec2_ebs_volume_size = {
        a = {
          size = 10
        }
        b = {
          size = 20
        }
      }
    }
    ec2_2 = {
      ami_id            = "ami-006dcf34c09e50022"
      instance_type     = "t1.micro"
      subnet_id         = "subnet-0ad1066b3d501c763"
      ec2_ebs_volume_size = {
        a = {
          size = 10
        }
        b = {
          size = 20
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Notice that each EBS volume now has its own unique key. I arbitrarily chose `a` and `b` here because I don't know what these objects represent in your system, but I would suggest choosing names that will make sense to future maintainers by describing what each disk is being declared for, such as "system" vs. "data", or whatever.

From this data structure it's possible to construct another data structure which is "inside out", with the EBS volumes as the top-level objects and each one specifying which EC2 instance it belongs to:

```
locals {
  ebs_volumes = tomap(merge(flatten([
    for inst_k, inst in var.ec2_details : [
      for vol_k, vol in inst.ec2_ebs_volumes : {
        "${inst_k}:${vol_k}" => {
          size         = vol.size
          instance_key = inst_k
        }
      }
    ]
  ])...)
}
```

The derived data structure would have the following result with the example input value I showed above:

```
tomap({
  "ec2_1:a" = {
    size         = 10
    instance_key = "ec2_1"
  }
  "ec2_1:b" = {
    size         = 20
    instance_key = "ec2_1"
  }
  "ec2_2:a" = {
    size         = 10
    instance_key = "ec2_2"
  }
  "ec2_2:b" = {
    size         = 20
    instance_key = "ec2_2"
  }
})
```

This value now meets the requirements for `for_each` over your EBS volumes, so all that remains is to write the two `resource` blocks:

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2_instance" {
  for_each = var.ec2_details

  ami           = each.value.ami_id
  subnet_id     = each.value.subnet_id
  instance_type = each.value.instance_type
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs_volume" {
  for_each = local.ebs_volumes

  availability_zone = aws_instance.ec2_instance[each.value.instance_key].availability_zone
  size              = each.value.size
}
```

Notice that we can use the `instance_key` attribute within `local.ebs_volumes` to cross-reference with the `aws_instance` objects to match up the EBS volume availability zones with the EC2 instance availability zones, which will be allocated automatically based on the subnet IDs.

The above configuration declares the following resource instances:

- `aws_instance.ec2_instance["ec2_1"]`
- `aws_instance.ec2_instance["ec2_2"]`
- `aws_ebs_volume.ebs_volume["ec2_1:a"]`
- `aws_ebs_volume.ebs_volume["ec2_1:b"]`
- `aws_ebs_volume.ebs_volume["ec2_2:a"]`
- `aws_ebs_volume.ebs_volume["ec2_2:b"]`

Terraform uses the keys from the map as part of the unique identifiers for the resource instances, so the EBS volumes have compound keys that include both the EC2 instance key and the EBS volume key, to prevent the EBS volume keys from one EC2 instance from colliding with another.

(Note: "resource instance" is a Terraform term for what you're declaring multiple of when you use `for_each`. It's not related to the term "EC2 instance", which is an AWS concept. This is a bit confusing in this case because we're declaring multiple instances of `ec2_instance`. )

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin. Such a detailed explanation on for_each usage. I have implemented logic to create multiple EC2 instances with identical values before and it was working as expected, so planning to create multiple EC2 instances with distinctive values using for_each. Now I am getting following error,                        
│ Error: Missing key/value separator
│
│   on local.tf line 5, in locals:
│    4:       for vol_k, vol in inst.ec2_ebs_volumes : {
│    5:         "${inst_k}:${vol_k}" => {
│
│ Expected an equals sign ("=") to mark the beginning of the attribute value.

Comment: It seems like I made a syntax error in that example somewhere, but I'm afraid I'm not at a computer right now so I can't test it to find out more. I'd suggest trying to match up the opening and closing brackets/parentheses/braces to see if they all seem to be in sensible matching pairs; probably I didn't nest something quite right and so Terraform's parser got confused.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working fine, there was a missing parentheses.
locals {
  ebs_volumes = tomap(merge(flatten([
    for inst_k, inst in var.ec2_details : [
      for vol_k, vol in inst.ec2_ebs_volume_size : {
        "${inst_k}:${vol_k}" = {
          size         = vol.size
          instance_key = inst_k
        }
      }
    ]
  ])...))
}

Comment: I have included device_name in terraform.tfvars like below. how to get volume_id and device_name?

ec2_details = {
  ec2_1 = {
    ami_id        = "ami-006dcf34c09e50022"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    subnet_id     = "subnet-09dc67828b86e0796"
    ec2_ebs_volume_size = {
      sdd = {
        size = 10
      }
      sde = {
        size = 20
      }
      sdf = {
        size = 30
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: resource "aws_volume_attachment" "volume_attachement" {
  for_each                                 = local.ebs_volumes
  volume_id                                = 
  device_name                              = 
  instance_id                              = aws_instance.ec2_instance[each.value.instance_key].id
}